# Pandas: create a table using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
ID  subdomain   search_engine   search_term code    category    term_code
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    yandex.ru   0   None    1   поисковая машина    1
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    my-shop.ru  0   None    5   интернет-магазин    1
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    ru.tele2.ru 0   None    10  Телеком-провайдеры  1
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    yandex.com  yandex  алиэкспресс 1   поисковая машина    6
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    fb.ru   0   None    3   информационный ресурс   1
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    shopotam.ru 0   None    4   интернет-агрегатор  1
031ce36695306ac09ae905927a753f33    ya.ru   0   None    1   поисковая машина    1
031ce36695306ac09ae905927a753f33    cyberforum.ru   0   None    3   информационный ресурс   1
031ce36695306ac09ae905927a753f33    fixim.ru    0   None    8   запчасти и ремонт   1
031ce36695306ac09ae905927a753f33    microsoft.com   0   None    9   сайты производителей с возможностью купить  1
031ce36695306ac09ae905927a753f33    market.yandex.ru    0   None    4   интернет-агрегатор  1
```

I need to get

```
ID, path
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca, поисковая машина -> интернет-магазин -> Телеком-провайдеры -> поисковая машина -> информационный ресурс -> интернет-агрегатор
031ce36695306ac09ae905927a753f33, поисковая машина -> информационный ресурс -> запчасти и ремонт -> сайты производителей с возможностью купить -> интернет-агрегатор
```

I mean I want to get column `term_code` and convert it to string with delimiter `->` to every `ID`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df.groupby('ID')['category'].apply(lambda x: ' -> '.join(list(x)))
```

Demo:

```
In [14]: df.groupby('ID')['category'].apply(lambda x: ' -> '.join(list(x)))
Out[14]:
ID
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca                        поисковая машина -> интернет-магазин -> Телеком-провайдеры -> 6 -> информационный ресурс
-> интернет-агрегатор
031ce36695306ac09ae905927a753f33    поисковая машина -> информационный ресурс -> запчасти и ремонт -> сайты производителей с возможностью купить
-> интернет-агрегатор
Name: category, dtype: object
```